# LULC using SAR data

Tags: remote-sensing, land-cover, land-classification, land-use

I have a Geocoded SAR data with me. I have to perform LULC classification. I have been given a shapefile (vector data) with the different LULC categories of the region. The region is mainly composed of Vegetation. So I have to determine the different vegetation categories from the SAR data. Can I do supervised classification by selecting AOI by having the vector data over the SAR data. The different types of vegetation in that region are already classified using SPOT image.

Is it advisable to perform supervised classification or should I be using any indices ?

Comment: I can't comment yet, but to answer your question it is necessary to know what kind of SAR data you have. Single polarimetric or dual/quadpolarimetric images? Amplitude/intensity images? Do you have a time series or multiple images?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using Dual Polarization ALOS Palsar data intensity images. I am having multiple images. 
As I said ealier, I am having a shapefile with the classes that are to be identified using the SAR data. I have extract these classes from the SAR data using the shapefile. I am trying to mask the regions from SAR data with shapefile in ERDAS Imagine. Am I on the right track?